# Issues with python lists, element being set to value I did not want

Tags: python, list, numpy

The relevant part of my code is here
*Edit: did not include the outer loop the first time.

```
for i in range(numAttributes): 
    for w in range(numFeatures):
        if X[i][w]!=0:
            print ("Setting nFeat[",y[i],"][",w,"]")
            self._Nfeat[y[i]][w]=1    
            print self._Nfeat[3][numFeatures-1]
            if self._Nfeat[3][numFeatures-1]!=0:
                print("y[i] is: ", y[i]," and w is: ", w)
                sys.exit()
```

essentially `self._Nfeat[3][numFeatures-1]` is being set to 1 when it shouldnt be. The `print` statements and final `if` statement are all put in for debugging.

The last 4 things output are:

```
0
setting nFeat[1][265676]
1
y[i] is 1 and w is 26576
```

I have also placed other if `self._Nfeat[3][numFeatures-1]!=0` checks in other places and determined it is definitely happening right before the current placement.

This has left me very confused as `self._Nfeat[3][numFeatures-1]` seems to be being changed when it shouldnt.

the list self._Nfeat is initialized in **init** with:

```
self._Nfeat=[]
```

At the start of the method it is then reinitialized with

```
self._Nfeat=[[0]*numFeatures]*numClasses
```

There is no where else in the code which deals with this list at all.

I am new to python and would appreciate any help greatly

Comment: You need to be more specific as your question is not clear. Apparently `y[i]` is `1`, yet you check for `nFeat[3]` instead of `nFeat[1]`. What is the reason for that?

Comment: I know that nFeat[3][265676] should not be set to 1 ever. However it is happening at this point in the code. The confusion comes from it been set to 1 at this part when nFeat[1] is being referred to.

Comment: You are most probably cloning the same list to generate your nested lists. In this case all the lists will point to the same memory location. Please post how do you instantiate `self._Nfeat` in the first place.

Comment: the class init has:  self._Nfeat = []


the method this is called in has: 

self._Nfeat=[[0]*numFeatures]*numClasses

Comment: I will also clarify, this method is only called once, and there is no where else in the code which deals with _Nfeat

Comment: Your inner list is been duplicated across all sublists. You should do: `self._Nfeat=[[0]*numFeatures for _ in range(numClasses)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your instantiation:

```
self._Nfeat=[[0]*numFeatures]*numClasses
```

This will copy (not clone!) the same list `numClasses` times, which will result in the bug you are experiencing. Change it to something like:

```
self._Nfeat = [[0] * numFeatures for _ in range(numClasses)]
```